# Can you assign an object to a remesh modifier? (might be a discussion question)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

So, I've been messing around with the remesh modifier in Blender 2.8 beta, and I was wondering if you can assign an object to the remesh modifier (kinda like a particle system). Is there a python script, or addon?

Comment: I'm unclear on what the question is,  something like Tissue Add-on? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whotRXc-9CA

Comment: Yes, but with the remesh. If you set it to blocks, it looks cool, but what if I want each block to look like a bunch of Suzanne heads? That's what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Really just modifying the remesh to have an object option.